# Как оптимизировать использование ЦП rainmeter

Tags: windows, оптимизация, виджет, rainmeter

Можно ли сделать скрипт для Rainmeter (или он уже есть) который будет приостанавливать обновление виджетов когда юзер не находится на рабочем столе. Это будет существенно снижать нагрузку на ЦП.
Направьте в поиске и помогите в рещении пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать чтобы останавливались виджеты. Нужно выполнить эти шаги:

1.Прейти на вкладу "Игровой режим".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.Поставить галочку на "Полноэкранные игры".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и все. Когда у вас открыты приложения или игры на весь экран то rainmeter отключает виджеты, они включатся если нет используемых полноэкранных приложений или игр. Если у вас есть приложения или игры которые тормозят из-за rainmeter то нужно поставить галочку в вкладке "Игровой режим" на
пункте "Дополнительные списки процессов" и добавить в список ваше приложение или игру. Надеюсь это вам поможет. Если нужно что-то спросить обращайтесь.